# She's been a vegetarian for ten years now

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> She's been a vegetarian **for ten years now**.

Does She continues to be vegetarian or no?

Comment: Yes. You may wish to research the [present perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect) tense.

Comment: Not necessarily, she has been a vegetarian for ten years, but it says nothing about the future.

Comment: @anouk I understood the OP's question to be "is she still a vegetarian" (i.e. in the present), as opposed to "she was a vegetarian for 10 years" which does _not_ imply that.

Answer (score 1):

"She has been a vegetarian" means that she was and continues to be a vegetarian. "For ten years now" means that, counting from today, she started being a vegetarian ten years ago.

To indicate that she was a vegetarian for ten years but is not anymore, you would say, "She had been a vegetarian for ten years but then quit" or even just "she was a vegetarian for ten years."

Comment: *counting from today*  this mean, one day ten years ago when she started being a vegetarian?

Comment: It doesn't have to be that specific. It could be counting from this year as well. I probably should have written "counting from the present time." Hopefully that makes sense.